# c++ insert into vector at known position

Tags: c++, stl, vector, insert

I wish to insert into a c++ vector at a known position. I know the c++ library has an insert() function that takes a position and the object to insert but the position type is an iterator. I wish to insert into the vector like I would insert into an array, using a specific index.

Comment: Actually my method is a bit redundant. Luca pointed out that you can just use the index easily without having to worry about retrieving the iterator.

Comment: You can't - there's no `insert` method that takes a position, all three overloads take iterators, which is probably why the other person deleted their answer.

Comment: note that inserting in the middle of a vector is quite slow, if you do that a lot you should consider using some other container

Comment: @f4: Though it should be profiled. The cache benefits a vector gives you may make up for the slowish middle-changes.

Comment: I think you are grabbing the iterator for the wrong vector. Namely I think "vertices.begin()+vnum+1" should be "new_mesh->Face(face_loc)->vertices.begin() + vnum + 1"

Comment: @myx: If you accept an answer you signal *"the question is solved"*. If its a different issue, open a new question.

Comment: @nevers1219: clearly I've been staring at my own code for far too long. Thanks so much! @gf: noted. I was going to open a new issue but then read nevets1219 comment and solved it.

Thank you everyone!

Comment: Out of interest, inserting at nth position is something Bjarne discussed in his keynote comparing vector and list and showing vector was far more efficient. Both are O(N) operations; for vector the insert is O(N) but finding the place to insert is constant. For list it's the other way round. vector will win on performance if the copying of the elements is very cheap e.g. ints. 

deque would also be O(N) unless the insertion position is the front where it beats vector. (At the back vector will be constant unless it needs to reallocate).

Comment: If you want a data structure where insert at position N is less complex you'd need an unordered binary tree. It would be O(log N) to find the Nth position and mostly constant to actually insert it but may require tree rebalancing which would be O(log N) at worst.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at that debugging trace. The last thing that's executed is std::copy(__first=0x90c6fa8, __last=0x90c63bc, __result=0x90c6878). Looking back at what caused it, you called insert giving the position to insert at as 0x90c63bc. std::copy copies the range [first, last) to result, which must have room for last - first elements. This call has last < first, which is illegal (!), so I'm guessing that the position you're giving to insert at is wrong. Are you sure vnum hasn't underflowed somewhere along the line? In GDB with that trace showing, you should run

> frame 10
>
> print vnum

to check. In fact, if you haven't just abbreviated in your question, I've just found your bug. Your second line is:

```
new_mesh->Face(face_loc)->vertices.insert(vertices.begin()+vnum+1, new_vertices[j]);
```

It should have been:

```
new_mesh->Face(face_loc)->vertices.insert(new_mesg->Face(face_loc)->vertices.begin()+vnum+1, new_vertices[j]);
```

The first line gives the insertion point relative to the start of some *other* variable called vertices, not the one you want to insert into.

Answer (score 24):

This should do what you want.

```
vector<int>myVec(3);
myVec.insert(myVec.begin() + INTEGER_OFFSET, DATA);
```

Please be aware that iterators may get invalidated when vector get reallocated. Please see this [site](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/insert/).

<strike>EDIT: I'm not sure why the other answer disappeared...but another person mentioned something along the lines of:</strike>

```
myVec.insert(INDEX, DATA);
```

If I remember correctly, this should be just fine.

Comment: Thanks for catching my mistake...my habit of setting things to null seems to have gotten the better of me. Also corrected mistake in code.

Comment: when I do this 

new_mesh->Face(face_loc)->vertices[vnum] = new_vertices[new_vertices.size()-1];

new_mesh->Face(face_loc)->vertices.insert(vertices.begin()+vnum+1, new_vertices[j]), I get a seg fault after the insert. Here, j=0, vnum=0, vertices is std:vector type

Comment: @myx: Is there a reason you're not using `std::vector`?

Comment: my c++ vector, I meant std::vector

Comment: Shouldn't be a vector issue, as it should get reallocated if the capacity is exceeded. Note this invalidates previous iterators as noted in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/insert/

Comment: new_vertices is declared as vector <R3MeshVertex *> new_vertices. Could it be an issue with pointers?

Comment: As Joe pointed out, you CANNOT use an integer to indicate the position but you can still use an "iterator + offset" to do what you want. I'll edit so that there's a clearer example of that.

Comment: thanks - I got the offset part working and now I'm trying to solve the mysterius seg fault. Can you take a look at my edited initial post?

Comment: Please refer to my comment in your question. I hope that's the issue.

Answer (score 9):

It's always nice to wrap these things up:

```
template <typename T>
T& insert_at(T& pContainer, size_t pIndex, const T::value_type& pValue)
{
    pContainer.insert(pContainer.begin() + pIndex, pValue);

    return pContainer;
}
```

That should do it. There is a now deleted answer that you can construct an iterator from an index, but I've never see that before. If that's true, that's definitely the way to go; I'm looking for it now.

Comment: is this equivalent to doing something like myVector.insert(myVector.begin()+index_num-1, object)?

Comment: @myx: It's exactly that, without the minus one.

Comment: This should be in the standard library.